# What phases of the JSF Life Cycle should get recalled on page refresh

Tags: jsf

What all phases of the JSF Life cycle should get called on page refresh

Answer (score 1):

That entirely depends on the kind of request (POST or GET) and the available parameters. A plain vanilla GET request for example would fire the first and last phases only. A "double submit" (refreshing a form submit) would by default go through all phases, but depending on the presence of the `immediate="true"` in `UIInput` and/or `UICommand` components, some phases might be skipped.

You can create yourself a simple `PhaseListener` and play around with it to learn which phases are executed and which not.

```
package mypackage;

import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;

public class LifeCycleListener implements PhaseListener {

    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
    }

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("START PHASE " + event.getPhaseId());
    }

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("END PHASE " + event.getPhaseId());
    }

}
```

Register it as follows in `faces-config.xml` to get it to run:

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>mypackage.LifeCycleListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

#### See also:

- [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html)